# Call with PSTN number created by bot established and immediatelly terminates

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to create a phone call with a MS Teams bot and a PSTN phone number using the Microsoft Graph API
I registered the MS Teams app and bot in Azure, registered a bot service and created a user for the bot in the Active Directory and assigned a phone number to him.
The bot and the app both have all calling permissions.

I am sending the following request to create a call between the bot and the PSTN phone number.

```json
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.call",
    "callbackUri": "{my-callback-uri}",
    "source": {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.participantInfo",
      "identity": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identitySet",
        "applicationInstance": {
          "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identity",
          "displayName": "Calling Bot",
          "id": "{id of bot user with phone number}"
        }
      },
      "countryCode": null,
      "endpointType": null,
      "region": null,
      "languageId": null
    },
    "targets": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.invitationParticipantInfo",
        "identity": {
          "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identitySet",
          "phone": {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identity",
            "id": "+41xxxxxxxxx"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "requestedModalities": [
      "audio"
    ],
    "mediaConfig": {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.serviceHostedMediaConfig"
    },
    "tenantId": "{tenant-id}"
}
```

This immediatelly returns the following response:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#communications/calls/$entity",
    "id": "{call-id}",
    "state": "establishing",
    "transferState": null,
    "terminationReason": null,
    "direction": "outgoing",
    "ringingTimeoutInSeconds": null,
    "subject": null,
    "callbackUri": "{my-callback-uri}",
    "requestedModalities": [
        "audio"
    ],
    "activeModalities": [],
    "routingPolicies": [],
    "tenantId": "{tenant-id}",
    "myParticipantId": "{participant-id}",
    "callChainId": "{callChain-Id}",
    "mediaHostedRegion": null,
    "mediaState": null,
    "resultInfo": null,
    "answeredBy": null,
    "chatInfo": null,
    "meetingInfo": null,
    "transcription": null,
    "callOptions": null,
    "meetingCapability": null,
    "breakoutDetails": null,
    "pstnDetails": null,
    "toneInfo": null,
    "incomingContext": null,
    "terminationSender": null,
    "meetingGroupDetails": null,
    "callRoutes": [],
    "source": {
        "endpointType": null,
        "region": null,
        "languageId": null,
        "countryCode": null,
        "participantId": null,
        "identity": {
            "user": null,
            "phone": null,
            "guest": null,
            "encrypted": null,
            "onPremises": null,
            "applicationInstance": {
                "id": "{bot-user-id}",
                "displayName": "Calling Bot",
                "tenantId": null,
                "registrantId": null
            },
            "application": null,
            "device": null
        }
    },
    "targets": [
        {
            "endpointType": null,
            "replacesCallId": null,
            "hidden": null,
            "removeFromDefaultAudioRoutingGroup": null,
            "participantId": null,
            "identity": {
                "user": null,
                "phone": {
                    "id": "+41xxxxxxxxx",
                    "displayName": null,
                    "tenantId": null,
                    "registrantId": null
                },
                "guest": null,
                "encrypted": null,
                "onPremises": null,
                "applicationInstance": null,
                "application": null,
                "device": null
            }
        }
    ],
    "mediaConfig": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.serviceHostedMediaConfig",
        "preFetchMedia": []
    }
}
```

Then on my callback I get the following two as 400 Bad Request

```json
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.commsNotifications",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.commsNotification",
            "changeType": "updated",
            "resource": "/app/calls/{call-id}",
            "resourceUrl": "/communications/calls/{call-id}",
            "resourceData": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.call",
                "state": "establishing",
                "callChainId": "{callChain-id}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

```json
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.commsNotifications",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.commsNotification",
            "changeType": "deleted",
            "resource": "/app/calls/{same-call-id}",
            "resourceUrl": "/communications/calls/{same-call-id}",
            "resourceData": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.call",
                "state": "terminated",
                "resultInfo": {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.resultInfo",
                    "code": 403,
                    "subcode": 510559,
                    "message": "Forbidden. DiagCode: 403#510559.@"
                },
                "callChainId": "{same-callChain-id}",
                "terminationSender": {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identitySet",
                    "phone": {
                        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identity",
                        "id": "+41xxxxxxxxx",
                        "displayName": "4:+41xxxxxxxxx",
                        "identityProvider": "None"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Sending the same request with a phone number assigned to a MS Teams user creates a call as expected. If I have multiple targets specified, a MS Teams user phone number and a PSTN phone number, only the MS Teams user gets called.
Calling the external phone number through MS Teams works too.

I already looked into all the Microsoft Forum posts and Github Discussions on the Microsoft Graph API Docs and Samples repositories and I haven't found any information to this type of error yet. There is also no information on the DiagCode 403#510559.@. (The DiagCode is always the same so I assume it is mapped to a certain type of error)

Similar requests with a phone number assigned to a MS Teams user work.
I am not sure If I am missing anything in how I setup the bot, the MS Teams app, the bot user etc. on Azure. But I am now through every documentation and forum post on that topic too.
I am suspecting that calling PSTN numbers as a bot via the Microsoft Graph API is not supported, but there are multiple sources on the forums and in the discussions that claim, that they got it working.

So what am I doing wrong here? Even information about that DiagCode 403#510559.@ or on the status of PSTN calling as a bot via the Microsoft Graph API would greatly help.

Some more solutions I have tried include:

- Different formats of the phone number (4:+41xxxxxxxxx, 071xxxxxxx, etc.) (same responses)
- Using the bot id and app id as source (fails)
- Creating a 1:1 Call with external phone number (fails)
- Using the beta version of the MS Graph Api (.../beta/communications/calls) (same responses)

**EDIT**:
As soon as I send the request for the call, I get in the Output-section of Visual Studio the following lines:

```
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

But I get this output for both the working request (calling an MS Teams phone number) and with the failing request (calling a PSTN number)

Comment: Could you please let us know if you see anything in the console logs as well?

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I included the console output in my question.

Comment: Sincere apologies for the long delay, could you please let us know if you are still facing this issue?

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/graph-api-create-a-pstn-call-and-invite-a-pstn-participant/m-p/2938855,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-9-create-peer-to-peer-pstn-call-with-service-hosted-media,, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communications-phone-number